# How to declare generic Map of Map

Tags: java, generics

How to declare such a Map where instead of Object I have specific type:

```
Map<Class, Map<String, ClassInstance>> map;
```

Such that could be used as:

```
Map<String, new Type()) valueMap = new HashMap();
map.put(Type.class, valueMap);
```

The problem is I can't figure out how to declare generic type of both 'Class' and 'ClassInstance'.

Comment: The better approach, following and adding to Andreas answer is to have util classes to do most casts for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Map<Class<?>, Map<String, Object>> map;
```

You cannot statically enforce that the `Object` is of the given type. That's for your code to enforce.

```
Map<String, Object> valueMap = new HashMap<>();
valueMap.put("Foo", new Type());
map.put(Type.class, valueMap);
```